# why if conditon is not behaving properly in comparing values

Tags: php, mysql

why if conditon is not behaving properly in comparing values one which is coming from database and other coming from form via post..inside while loop of mysql fetch array

```
<?php
$right=0;
$wrong=0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mcq") ;
$total =mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "total questions are :".$total;
    echo "<br>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $b=$row['id'];
                $a=$_POST['a_'.$b];
                $cor=$row['correct'];
                    if($a==$cor)
                        $right++;
                    else
                        $wrong++;
            }
```

$a is coming from radio buttons from previous page and $cor is coming from database..i m comparing selected value of radio button with cor(correct answer of that value) which is coming from data base.. but condition is not executing rightly so please help me!!!!

Comment: Did you try to echo $a and $cor to see their content ?

Comment: Throw `$b` in there too, as you're using it to retrieve `$a`

Comment: Unless is a very small project I would recommend using somekind of framework. Also try printing (echo) the contents to see if they match. Other issue could be the type of each value, for example string and integer

Comment: yes sir i have tried and values are printing

Comment: What is not executing rightly? You're only assigning values. Enable error reporting as well. `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` in top of the file

Comment: i m not getting proper results like if i have chosen a right option and if it matches with correct option frm database then $right should increment by one and if there is wrong optn that dont match with value at database then wrong should increment by one but this is not hapening

Comment: but even if i enabled ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL); then also there is not showing any eror

Answer (score 1):

The radio button just send one value. Your way to retrieve it is wrong, because you are basing in the ID, but the id should be used in the value.

Usually in HTML you should use some like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="item1" />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="item2" />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="item3" checked />
```

So, you should try to get the value from post:

```
$myvar = $_POST["myradio"];
```

Can you paste the radio button code?

Comment: hile($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>" .' Q '.$n. "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['question'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['a'] . "<input type='radio'name='a_".$row['id']."' value='$row[a]'/>". "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['b'] ."<input type='radio' name='a_".$row['id']."' value='$row[b]'/>". "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['c'] ."<input type='radio' name='a_".$row['id']."' value='$row[c]'/>". "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['d'] ."<input type='radio' name='a_".$row['id']."' value='$row[d]'/>" ."</td>";

echo "</tr>";

Comment: You are sending this $row[a] what probably will not work. Should be something like $row['a']

Comment: The same in the other values $row[b] and $row[c]. I think the outcome of this is empty, so you never will find the color.

Comment: but values are coming on next page